# Reset idleTimeout counter between ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using JQuery idleTimeout plugin from here :

http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-idle-timeout/example-mint.htm

I'm using it in an mvc 4 application.

Below is the code snippet where i set the session timer.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var sessionTimer = 60;
  $(document).ready(function ()
  {
    // setup the dialog
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 210,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            'Yes, Keep Working': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            'No, Logoff': function () {
                // fire whatever the configured onTimeout callback is.
                // using .call(this) keeps the default behavior of "this" being the warning
                // element (the dialog in this case) inside the callback.
                $.idleTimeout.options.onTimeout.call(this);
            }
        }
    });


        var $countdown = $("#dialog-countdown");

        @* start the idle timer plugin *@
        $.idleTimeout('#dialog', '#dialog-button-yes', {
            idleAfter: (sessionTimer - 30),
            keepAliveURL: '@Url.Action("KeepAlive", "Home")',
            pollingInterval: 5,
            serverResponseEquals: 'OK',
            AJAXTimeout: 250 * 60,
            onTimeout: function () {
                window.location = '@Url.Action("Logout", "Login")';
        },
        onIdle: function () {
            $(this).dialog("open");
        },
        onCountdown: function (counter) {

            $countdown.html(counter); @* update the counter *@
        }
    });
  });
```

This code is placed in the outermost/shared view. All my pages are loaded using partial views using jquery $.ajax. The above code is loaded only once, the sessionTimer gets set to 60 seconds. So the timer does not resets when a new page gets loaded calling ajax post. Even though the user is active, the timer is ticking between the posts.
Is there a way for me to reset the counter every time an ajax post takes place.
I can reset this on every inner views $.ajax success condition. But there are too many places. I would like to know if there is a common code I can write on this master page of mine, that will let me know that an ajax call has been placed and to reset the counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `.ajaxSuccess()` event handler from jQuery. You can check the documentation on how to use it here: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/ .

Comment: well I tried the same thing but not working for me... can you illustrate how you have done I have attached the ajaxSuccess with document

Comment: @BhavikBamania I haven't used it in this particular case. My answer has the documentation linked for further reading. It must be attached to document and will trigger whenever a jQuery ajax request is successful.

Comment: I tried the same but it is appending into the existing timer instead of resuming

Comment: I'm unsure that I can help you in the context of this answer with such little information. Please consider making a question with your code.